# Get all values from List<> instead of just 1 index and print this in RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I have a problem. I download JSON from my PHP script:

```
[{
    "Nazwa": "Rower",
    "Cena": "300"
}, {
    "Nazwa": "Rower mtb",
    "Cena": "350"
}]
```

This script downloading JSON:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    public List<Post> postList;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final String name = editText.getText().toString();

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        String URL =         "https://shoppingcentreeshop.000webhostapp.com/androidAppScripts/szukajProduk    tu.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            Log.v(TAG, response);
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            Type type = new TypeToken<List<Post>>(){}.getType();
            postList = gson.fromJson(response, type);

            int size = postList.size();
            Log.v(TAG, "SIZE = "+size);

            RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, postList);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
        {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>    ();

            params.put("name_product", name);
            return params;
        }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

I parse this using GSON to this class:

```
public class Post
{
    @SerializedName("Nazwa")
    @Expose
    private String nazwa;
    @SerializedName("Cena")
    @Expose
    private String cena;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I adding **postList** to RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    List<Post> listPost;
    Context context;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> list)
{
    context = mContext;
    listPost = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item_layout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    final Post post = listPost.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(post.getCena());
    holder.price.setText(post.getCena());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return listPost.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView title;
    TextView price;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleNazwa);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    }
}
}
```

Why in my recyclerview I have only text from first index in **postList**.

I know, there is a lot of code, but I don't know where is problem in code.

I use JSON to get data from server to RecyclerView first time 
so please bear with me

Comment: Does `Log.v` print correct size? Could you attach recycler_view_item_layout and activity_main?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted Android Studio, and this is working !
I don't know why !